Slow Angular web component render performance
I am using Angular's elements package to create web components that can be reused across my site.
I have an api call that causes around 2000 web component elements to be rendered at once. This takes around 2 seconds while rendering a simple div for the same request is almost instant.
Is there anything I can do to increase the performance for web components?
I have created a minimum reproducible example on Github: https://github.com/jeroen1602/slow-web-components
This project includes a single web component to show the problem. It then simulates the big number of elements needing to be rendered like so:
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
let componentBadge = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  componentBadge += `<custom-badge>${i}</custom-badge>`;
}
output.innerText = componentBadge;

I have already tried:

Setting the specific component's encapsulation to Emulated, None, and ShadowDom.
Setting the changeDetection strategy to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

Edit
I'm getting comments to implement cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport but as far as I can see this requires a complete Angular context.
I am using a simple LAMP stack that generates HTML that contains many angular web components, for example:
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><custom-badge>1</custom-badge></td></tr>
    <tr><td><custom-badge>2</custom-badge></td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td><custom-badge>n</custom-badge></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

In this context template directives like *ngFor, or *cdkVirtualFor aren't available.
I have tried to make another virtual-scroll web component that would use the CDK virtual scroll under the hood by adding or removing html slots.
<virtual-scroll number-of-elements="n">
   <custom-badge slot="index-1">1</custom-badge>
   <custom-badge slot="index-2">2</custom-badge>
   ...
   <custom-badge slot="index-n">n</custom-badge>
</virtual-scroll>

Where the component would render like so
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="20">
  <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let element of elements(); trackBy: trackBy">
    <div>
      <slot name="index-{{element}}"></slot>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './virtual-scroll.component.html',
  styleUrl: './virtual-scroll.component.scss',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class VirtualScrollComponent {

  @Input({ required: true })
  public set numberOfElements( n: number ) {
    const elements = Array.from({length: n}).map((_, i) => i);
    this.elements.set(elements);
  }

  protected elements: WritableSignal<number[]> = signal([]);

  protected trackBy(index: number, value: number): number {
    return value;
  }

}

This did perform a bit better but it still isn't very performant  because the elements are still created even though they may not be rendered to the screen (yet).

You can use @angular/cdk for virtual scrolling for performance optimization

You will never, ever need 2000 components rendered at the same time. Optimize that and you're good to go.

Really, using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport is ridiculous easy, an e.g. in this SO

Or add a trackby in the ngFor directive if needed
